# Parse iOS SDK: Converting and performing operations on Date object

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

**Scenario**

In my app I am using the parse.com framework and will be displaying posts made by certain users. The posts that are displayed will contain a few pieces of information including the "createdAt" property. The "createdAt" property that parse automatically creates for each post goes like this...

```
2014-09-23 17:55:55 +0000
```

**What I'm doing with the parse created Date**

I took the parse created date and I'm breaking it apart at the "date" and "time" parts...

```
NSString *parseDateAndTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", object.createdAt];

NSArray *postDateSplit = [parseDateAndTime componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

NSLog(@"parse date = %@", [postDateSplit objectAtIndex:0]);

NSLog(@"parse time = %@", [postDateSplit objectAtIndex:1]);
```

Logs out...

[image]

**What I need**

I want to be able to inform my users on when each post was posted. **If it was posted that day, then how many hours ago. If it was posted that hour, then how many minutes ago.** I think you get the drift.

(I need something *like* this **pseudo code**)...

```
NSTimeInterval interval = [object.createdAt timeIntervalSinceNow];

if (interval = today) {

    if (interval > sixHoursAgo) {

        self.dateLabel.text = @"earlier today";

    }

    else if (interval < sixHoursAgo) {

        if (interval < oneHourAgo) {

            self.dateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@m ago", numberOfMinutes];

        }

        else {

            self.dateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@hrs ago", numberOfHours];

        }

    }

    else {

        self.dateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"today at %@", time];
    }

}

else if (interval = yesterday) {

    self.dateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"yesterday at %@", time];

}

else {

    self.dateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ at %@", date, time];

}
```

**Question**

How do I get this logic above to work in actual code?

Comment: Why are you not using NSDateFormatter to parse the date?  Then use NSDateComponents for your other values.

Comment: You know the code I can not only determine which each time is more recent but also calculate the exact time difference?

Comment: Looking at your code more closely it appears that you already have an NSDate object as input and you're bogusly converting it into string using stringWithFormat.  Don't do that!  It invokes NSDate.description which is only for debug use.  Instead, actually read the documentation and use NSDateComponents to extract your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not reinvent the wheel!
Convert it to a date and use a lib like NSDate+TimeAgo :

https://github.com/kevinlawler/NSDate-TimeAgo

Comment: Nice! This little guy is awesome.